# scala spray respondWithHeader dynamic value?

Tags: scala, spray

How might I specify a respondWithHeader call so that it is added at request time?

I'm doing something like:

```
def receive: Receive =
  runRoute(
    withDynamicHeaders {
      inner.routes 
    }
  )

def withDynamicHeaders: Directive0 = {
   HttpHeaders.RawHeader(
     "Some-Header", generateValueHere
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized I can do this with the `dynamic` directive.